# Autocomplete в программе Conemu

Tags: autocomplete

Как в программе Conemu (надстройка над терминалом) сделать функцию автозаполнения пути и команд.
(Я имею ввиду как в продвинутых текстовых редакторах. Начинаешь вводить путь а он предлагает варианты).

Есть вообще такая возможность? Гугление подсказало, что такое, вроде как возможно сделать для Git bash. Ну а Conemu может работать с Git bash.

Comment: Начните с чтения документации по используемому шеллу и кнопке Tab.

Comment: Спасибо, до Tab уже добрался. Как, оказалось, что и в git-bash да и powershell при вводе начальных букв пути или файла при нажатии Tab,  и срабатывает автодополнение. Но срабатывает только когда уходишь по дальше от корня диска. C:/

Comment: Если нажимать в корне C:/ (или вообще любого диска) даже веденное почти целиком имя директории не приводит к срабатыванию автодополнения. Вот такие особенности:)

Comment: Так при чем здесь ConEmu? Спрашивайте в теме (или у авторов) git-bash, если вы его используете...

Comment: ConEmu тут особенно и не причем, просто через нее на windows 7 вроде как удобно работать с терминалом. И git-bash через нее ConEmu запускаю. А вопрос  в целом решен. Еще раз спасибо, что ответили.

Comment: Задавая вопрос в правильной теме шансы получить правильный ответ повышаются в разы...